# Typescript write common library

Tags: typescript

I'm learning typescript and I'm at very basic level. I would like to write a common typescript library and this library must have multiple utils classes:  class1, class2 class3, class4 .... 
After that I would like bundle all this classes in one js bundle file eg: myLib.js

In other typescript project I want use this js library, and I import it in my HTML file as vanilla javascript file and i want use it in my project with all types definition of classes.

I thought this approach because if I run updates on my library I will release it on server folder, and in this way I update only myLib.js and not other project that use it.
I don't now if this way is the correct choice and I ask you if you can help me to understand this part.

How can do it?

Comment: Please provide code snippets.

Comment: I don't have a code for me is important understand  the correct way to do it..after that I write my code.

Comment: I provided a link to a resource that may be useful for declaration of common libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can contribute to such a vague question, is read: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html